# AJAX jQuery Success but no change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay so I got this txt file that I'm reading from the wamp local server,

I make changes to this text and try to send it back to the file

the ajax request fires the success function but the file doesn't change, any ideas? thanks

Code:

```
var customCss = "";
var customCssPath = "http://localhost:8081/userThemer/styles/custom.css";
var newStyle ="newwww";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: customCssPath,//url of receiver file on server
        data: newStyle, //your data
        success: function () {
            console.log("YAY !");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log(":'(");
        },
        dataType: "text" //text/json...
    });
```

Comment: You're posting data to a CSS file... is that right? Check the network tab of the console to see the exact state of the request.

Comment: What is actually *handling* the request server-side?  The web server may be successfully returning the CSS file for any HTTP verb (in this case POST), but that doesn't mean it's actually *doing anything* with the data you posted.  What mechanism do you have in place to actually use the posted data on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just understand the **[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'xyz.php',      // url of receiver file on server            
        type: 'POST',   // send method, either POST or GET          
        data: data,     // data to be sent to $url
        dataType: 'text',  // tells what kind of respnse you get
        success: function ( response ) {   // success call with response
            console.log("WOW! your respnose is" + response );
        },
        error: function () {   // error 
            console.log("ERROR Occured!!");
        }
    });
```

**Update:**

In Your recevier file ( as I mention **xyz.php** ), `echo` your desired response like:

```
 <?php 
    echo 'this is a response from xyz.php file';
 ?>
```

Comment: it responses my original files text

Comment: see updated answer @JosephKhella

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
console.log("YAY !");
},
```

Please try this way. You can get the data.

Comment: I'm trying to POST data not GET'

Comment: Sorry if you tries with POST, what is the response from the data?